# MVVM is of which type of design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, mvvm, architecture

After searching the net and reading about design patterns I came across 3 categories i.e.  **behavioral, creational, and structural** design pattern (GOF).

I have been working with MVVM for some time. I wanted to know that MVVM falls into which category.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Model-view-view model is an *architectural* pattern, a category of patterns that the GoF book doesn't mention.

An architectural pattern describes how to organize an entire application or subsystem ("programming in the large") while the traditional patterns give solutions for smallscale problems ("programming in the small"). More info: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architectural_pattern

Answer (score 1):

+1 to @Joni's answer. What I would add is that following on from the GoF, you should read Fowler's Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture. For me, this is a natural progression and demonstrates a wide range of key architectural patterns.

While MVVM is not in the book, the beginnings of 'separated presentation'-type patterns are (MVC). IMHO, it's important to understand the progression of these types of patterns and the motives for creating them. You can see the beginnings of MVVM in the [Presentation Model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html) pattern.